# Modify XML file at specific node

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml like this

```
<list>
<job>
    <id>B001</id>
    <name>Job1</name>
    <time>7</time>
    <status>success</status>
</job>
<job>
    <id>B002</id>
    <name>Job2</name>
    <time>1</time>
    <status>success</status>
</job>
```

I want to change the  at specific job with a specific name. I did some search on google but it's no help.Anyone know a good way to do this in Java? Or a doc will also be appreciated. 
I wonder a method which might be `changeTimeOfJob(String id, int time)`

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org)

```
public String changeTimeOfJob(String id, int time){
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "", Parser.xmlParser());
    String selection = "job > id:contains("+id+")";
    Element resultLinks = doc.select(selection).first();
    resultLinks.parent().select("time").first().text(String.valueOf(time));
    return doc.html(); // Gives you the resulting XML you can write back to file
}
```

If you have the xml as String, use:

```
String html = "<YOURXML>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

Look in https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax for further information.

Edit: Put in the selector for you. 
Edit2: Updated full code

Edit3: I actually tested it now, there were some errors before.

Comment: I want to overwrite the element at a specific node, not to parse the file

Comment: Once you found the element you can set the attribute and put it back to a file.